# Mostly Introverted/Avoidant Psyche

Tags: xenobiology, psychology

I have a species with mostly avoidant and introverted personalities. They prefer to stay in small, nomadic groups and flee when the surrounding population becomes too large.

The criterion for "too many people" is met internally by measuring the intensity and duration of surrounding stimuli, especially noise. Too much noise and the creature attempts to find a way out.

**Why would this happen? What evolutionary advantages does this provide for a creature with human-level intelligence?**

Comment: Human level intelligence developed in a team environment. A single naked ape is powerless, a team of naked apes can kill lion, elephants and whales which are bigger than them.

Comment: See Pierson's Puppeteers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Resource management.

The most obvious resource to manage is food. Large apex predators (e.g., tigers, bears, etc.) tend to be solitary, and maintain territories, because there's only so  much food to go around--and too many of them in one territory will exhaust the food supply, and starve.

There, are, however, advantages to not being *completely* alone. For one, working in groups lets smaller predators take down larger prey--essentially, acting like a single larger predator. This what lets wolves take down moose, and humans take down elephants. (Conversely, it allows prey animals to more effectively protect each other from predators.) Additionally, living in groups allows specialization of skills, and living in multi-generational groups allows parents and grandparents to teach children. So, for a creature in a certain range of sizes, acting primarily or exclusively as a predator in an environment with a limited food supply, there is a balance between managing the food supply and getting the benefits of group living that can lead to living in small groups, but feeling driven to break apart if the population gets too big.

Similar forces can arise from the need to manage other resources. E.g., mates. Among elephants, for example, males are kicked out of the herd at adolescence, because keeping them around causes problems. You can only have so many adult males in one band before they start killing things. It's not too hard to imagine a species where one or both sexes "decides" (i.e., evolves towards the attitude) that rather than wasting energy competing for the best mates in a larger pool, it's more effective to divide up into smaller groups--*any* smaller groups--and just compete in the smaller pool that results, effectively avoiding the paradox of choice.

Another, somewhat more abstract, resource is *risk*. If these creatures are *not* unchallenged apex predators (or big, burly, nasty herbivores that no predator would dare attack), then there will be evolutionary pressures to avoid their own predators. There are lots of ways to do that--live in *huge* herds and just accept the losses, develop armor or weapons, get really fast... or *hide*. If one of their primary methods of avoiding predators is to *hide* from them, it's a lot easier to do that if your social group is relatively small, and nomadic. Again, however, this need will be in tension with the benefits of social living, so you'll get a balance where complete solitude is bad, and large groups are bad, but small groups are just right.

Answer (score 7):

## What is [Introversion](http://www.myersbriggs.org/my-mbti-personality-type/mbti-basics/extraversion-or-introversion.htm?bhcp=1)?

For a lot of people, their understanding of introversion is **wrong**. It isn't shyness or being reclusive. *It is thinking before acting, and focusing on quality of relationships over quantity.*

Introverts don't dislike people. In fact, they enjoy knowing a few people really well. They would prefer playing a board game with their best friends over going dancing with 100+ strangers. Everyone displays introverted and extroverted traits: *you can color outside your little box*. This is true if you're doing [Meyers-Briggs](https://youtu.be/_NQqSnkI32A) or [The Big 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Five_personality_traits) or any other personality system.

I should also note that I'm assuming that these creatures have human-like minds and social values.

## Technology and Progress

Let's get this straight: introversion and extroversion have nothing to do with intelligence, creativity, or resourcefulness. [Richard Feynman](https://youtu.be/JIJw3OLB9sI) was an extrovert, but also a famous scientist. [J.K. Rowling and Steven Spielberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraversion_and_introversion#Introversion) are identified as an introverts, but they're big in the entertainment industry! Introversion may help people realize what they have sooner, but it may also prevent them from sharing.

Introversion vs extroversion is, in my opinion, not nearly as important to innovation and intelligence as the availability of resources or openness to new experiences. "Openness to new experiences" is a big 5 personality trait, so you can be a hardcore intro- or extro-vert and be anywhere on the "openness to new experiences" axis.

On the other hand, religion and science may be more appealing, because they attempt to explain why the world works. For a person who thinks a lot of about what is going on, as introverts generally do, these answers are very appealing.

## Disease and Biological Fitness

Because people would live in smaller, more isolated groups, disease transmission would slow down. Not that disease wouldn't spread, but that people spending less time with massive amounts of other people would slow things down considerably! This is one biological advantage for introversion.

[Cities have been a drain on the human population](https://youtu.be/JEYh5WACqEk?t=2m59s) for a very long time, and not always appealing to introverts. More introverted/avoidant people can possibly avoid plagues because of "noisy cities."

## Summary

In all, increased introversion may lead to a more responsible, less reactionary, and definitely different kind of people. I would expect more religion and more science. I would expect smaller city-states to be a popular form of government and maybe less plagues. Inaction, indecision, and [tribalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tribalism) may be the behavioral plagues of these people.